# Import/Export/Copy table/(sub)partition statistics in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have some oracle tables with partitions (and suppartions). My aim is, whenever I create a new partition to copy all the statistics from the latest partition to the new one.

I have found the following ways to do that

- dbms_stats.copy_table_stats
- dbms_stats.get_table_stats and then dbms_stats.set_table_stats
- dbms_stats.export_table_stats and then dbms_stats.import_table_stats

However, I could not find the difference between those methods.

As I understand `copy_table_stats` is the newest addition and if I am not mistaken it is available after 10.2.0.4 version. The get/set and export/import methods need some stats manipulation in order to work (e.g Update C2 in stats table).

Am I correct? I have not found somewhere documented, how each one method handles the suppartitions, for example for `copy_table_stats` I need to copy also the subpartition statistics after copping the partition statistics. Is this also true for the other methods?

In general is there any significant difference between those 3 methods? What should I consider? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use **get/set** (and probably dbms_stats.convert_raw_value) if you want to re-set and modify some stat values.

**export/import** is useful when the goal is to release (apply) stats on another instance or drop table, re-create it and copy (some) stats afterwards. You need auxiliary table to preserve stats in this case.

**copy** stats is ideal and typical way to achieve your goal.

**Update**

To find quick explanation just type keywords and "white paper" in google

(I found below links using `white paper dbms_stats copy_stats`)

[Understanding Optimizer Statistics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-optimizer-stats-concepts-110711-1354477.pdf)

and with all the latest changes

[Understanding Optimizer Statistics With Oracle Database 12c Release 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-statistics-concepts-12c-1963871.pdf)